# Edges of what kind of graph may not be partitioned as triangles?

Tags: graph-theory, triangles

I would like to know edges of what kind of graph may not be partitioned as triangles? As an example edges of one of these graphs $K_7 , k_{12} , K_{3,3,3} , K_{5,5,5}$ may not be partitioned as triangles but I don't know which one it is!

All came to my mind to solve this problem is, the number of edges must be $3x$ so I tried this for the above graphs: ($K_{n,n,n}$ is a 3-partitioned graph and each partition has $n$ vertices)

$$K_7: |E| = 21$$
$$K_{12}: |E| = 66$$ 
$$K_{3,3,3}: |E| = 27$$ 
$$K_{5,5,5}: |E| = 75$$

and sounds it doesn't work!

Comment: @Casteels vertex degrees must be $2,4,6,...$ yes?

Comment: So the answer is $k_{12}$. thanks

Comment: @RespawnedFluff $K_4$ has $6$ edges so by removing one of the edges, then $|E| \neq 3x$ . The meaning of partition means, every edge must involve in to exactly one triangle.

Comment: You guys seem to have a different notion of partition in mind than I had.

Comment: I had to [re]parse that question a couple of times... You're asking about edge-partitioning. (In CS the more common problem is vertex-partitioning into triangles; that's actually one of the original 21 NP-complete problems.) And "it doesn't work" in the question here means that what you found (3 divides |E|) is a necessary but not a sufficient condition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Show that if the edge set can be partitioned into triangles, then every vertex must have even degree.

(This rules out exactly one of your examples, although it might still be the case that the edge set of another one cannot be partitioned into triangles.)